# Proper punctuation for parentheses

Tags: parentheses

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [Is there any rule for the placement of space after and before parenthesis?](https://english.stackexchange.com/questions/5987/is-there-any-rule-for-the-placement-of-space-after-and-before-parenthesis)

Should you put a space in between the outside of parentheses and punctuation?

Answer (score 3):

#### Inside Spacing

> You should not use parentheses incorrectly ( like this ), you should use them correctly (like this).

#### Full Parenthetical Sentence

> (When writing a full sentence, put the final punctuation inside the closing parenthesis.)

#### Outside spacing

> You should not use parentheses incorrectly (like this) , but rather correctly (like this), with no space before the comma.