# Do parentheses need spaces either side?

Tags: orthography, spacing

I should place parentheses after a space or without any spacing? Which one of below sentences is right?

> 1. We adopted DM (Data Mining) in this lecture.
> 2. We adopted DM(Data Mining) in this lecture.

Comment: Yes, generally you put the spaces outside but not inside.  You occasionally see a (reasonably literate) writing style that violates this rule, though.  And computer programmers (who are by definition only slightly literate) are apt to do it many different ways, based on how they habitually space things when "coding".

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Is there any rule for the placement of space after and before parenthesis?](https://english.stackexchange.com/questions/5987/is-there-any-rule-for-the-placement-of-space-after-and-before-parenthesis)

Comment: Spaces before and after if adjacent to words.  Perhaps not if adjacent to punctuation.  Similar to the rule about spaces before and after words.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

The first. Parentheses should have spaces on either side, just like words. For example (taken from [The Punctuation Guide](http://www.thepunctuationguide.com/parentheses.html)):

> Parentheses (always used in pairs) allow a writer to provide additional information. The parenthetical material might be a single word, a fragment, or multiple complete sentences.

Answer (score 3):

Yes, parentheses have spaces before and after the enclosure (your example #1).  However, there is never a space between a closing parenthesis and another piece of punctuation (like the period in this or the last sentence).

Unrelated to your question, the actual word for an acronym is normally used first and then is followed by the acronym presented in parentheses.  This is to establish what the acronym will mean for the rest of the paper.

> The lecture encouraged us to adopt Data Mining (DM), but I was still on the fence.  DM is an important feature in...